# How does the topology of minimal surfaces depend on the radius?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

Let $M^n \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$ be a smooth, properly embedded minimal surface, with boundary $\partial M$. The convex hull property states that $M$ is contained inside the convex hull of its boundary.

This has a few topological consequences: the following is an example. Suppose $0 \in M$, and $\rho = \mathrm{dist}(0,\partial M)$. Then, for all $0 < r < \rho$, the inclusion $M \cap B_r \subset M$ induces an injection on the $(n-1)$th homology group:
\begin{equation}
H_{n-1}(M \cap B_r;R) \subset H_{n-1}(M;R),
\end{equation}
regardless of the coefficient ring $R$. (This is Lemma 1.11 in the book of Colding and Minicozzi [1].)

**Question.** Is there any additional information on the topology of $M \cap B_r$, and how it depends on the radius? For example, presumably the relation above fails for the other homology groups—which surfaces demonstrate this?

[1] Colding, Tobias Holck; Minicozzi, William P., II. *A course in minimal surfaces.* Graduate Studies in Mathematics, Vol. 121. American Mathematical Society, 2011.